# CocoaPods doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I stalled the latest version of CocoaPod but it doesn't work. It shows the error message below.

I don't know what's wrong with it.
I followed the tutorials and I thought the installation process should be simple and easy.
But it doesn't work for me.

```
Ld build/Debug-iphoneos/sdf.app/sdf normal armv7s
    cd /Users/compass/GoogleDrive/Projects/Story2Movie/Development/iOS/Story2Movie_0.1/test/sdf
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/compass/GoogleDrive/Projects/Story2Movie/Development/iOS/Story2Movie_0.1/test/sdf/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/compass/GoogleDrive/Projects/Story2Movie/Development/iOS/Story2Movie_0.1/test/sdf/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/compass/GoogleDrive/Projects/Story2Movie/Development/iOS/Story2Movie_0.1/test/sdf/build/sdf.build/Debug-iphoneos/sdf.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/sdf.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-sdf -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/compass/GoogleDrive/Projects/Story2Movie/Development/iOS/Story2Movie_0.1/test/sdf/build/sdf.build/Debug-iphoneos/sdf.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/sdf_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/compass/GoogleDrive/Projects/Story2Movie/Development/iOS/Story2Movie_0.1/test/sdf/build/Debug-iphoneos/sdf.app/sdf

ld: library not found for -lPods-sdf
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: when your link fails you should check to see if the big L includes the path for your library `-L/path/to/libdir` also if it is there, check with file command to see if you have the correct arch

Comment: When do you get that message? Did you create your Podfile and run `pod install` successfully?

Comment: Are you using the newly created .xcworkspace file? I remember I had this error, when I continued to use the .xcodeproj file when I should use the workspace instead. Remember that you have to use the Xcode workspace CocoaPods created for you after pod install in order to use the pods.

Comment: @KaiEngelhardt I saw "[!] From now on use<code>Story2Movie.xcworkspace' this on the command line. Doesn't it mean the .xcworkspace file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://cocoapods.org just follow all these steps. It's much easier doing it like this.

Comment: That's what I did but it didn't work for me. It's very frustrating.

Comment: This  is not a good answer and this is a very good question since that is not so easy to install.. in fact there are some workarounds that you must do to get cocoapod working.. for example just to make ´pod setup´ takes a lot of time.. and you must to do some workaround that are not explained there.